# Can large amount of page cache lead to OOM in other processes?

Tags: hdfs

I ran HDFS on those linux machines. I used "-Xmx" and "-Xms" to assign datanode 25GB memory. But when hdfs used only 10GB memory, it throws out an Out-Of-Memory exception, and meanwhile, the "cached memory" is about "50GB"(the server I used has 64GB total memory).

So I guess it's page cache that occupied the system memory and led to OutOfMemory in HDFS, is this possible?

And it seems there's no such a parameter "cache_stop" in CentOS 6.3 which is the os that I use, is there any other way to stop page cache?